# 500 not valid database

Tags: joomla

I'm using Joomfish component then it give error "500 not valid database" For my Component.
When I changed my database MySQL to mysqli then it's working fine.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are running PHP 5.3, the mysqli extension is not installed by default. You probably haven't installed it, or it isn't configures properly.

Please check the `phpinfo()` function to see if it is installed and [read about setting up mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.setup.php) to see how to install and/or configure it.